# Calling a method in If block Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to call an apex method in If block in visualforce .my page segment is

```
<apex:outputText  value="{!IF (IsFbConnected,'Facebook is Connected','Facebook is not Connected')}" />
```

and my apex method in controller is

```
 public Boolean IsFbConnected(){
  return false;
  }
```

and its giving me error while saving:Unknown Property  MyController.IsFbConnected.please tell the right way to call an apex method .is it possible or not ??

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible. Currently it's not accessible by the salesforce getter logic to the VF page. You'll have to make your method called to get your boolean value as such `getIsFbConnected`. Below is how it will look like:

```
public Boolean getIsFbConnected(){
    return false;
}
```

Your VF page can stay the same.

As @GreenStork said:

> Your property needs a getter to be accessible to your page. Here is alternative syntax: public Boolean isFbConnected { get; private set; }

Comment: Your property needs a getter to be accessible to your page. Here is alternative syntax: public Boolean isFbConnected { get; private set; }

Comment: To recap:  all variable getters must be prefixed with 'get', so your method name should be called "getIsFbConnected()" but you'll reference it on your VF page by "{!isFbConnected}"

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use this approach:

```
class MyClass
{
   // Define a boolean property
   public Boolean isFbConnected {get; set;}

   public MyClass()
   { 
      isFbConnected = IsFbConnected();
   }

   public Boolean IsFbConnected()
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```